# Where can the variable in jsp be defined except java classes?

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans, el

Suppose I have the following code:

```
<c:when test="${isFoo}">
```

Where can isFoo be defined except:

1. java classes
2. `<c:set ... />` construction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In JSP itself by *scriptlets*. E.g. as a request attribute:

   ```
   <% request.setAttribute("isFoo", true); %>
   ```

   *Scriptlets* are however [discouraged](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html) since over a decade.

   ---
2. By an implicit EL variable. E.g. as a request parameter:

   > http://example.com/page.jsp?isFoo=true

   Which can be accessed by `${param}`:

   ```xml
   <c:if test="${param.isFoo}">
   ```

   There are many more, you can find them all in [this overview](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij).

   ---

#### See also:

- [Our EL (Expression Language) tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Answer (score 2):

You can also set it using [c:set](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/). For instance:

`<c:set var="isFoo" value="true" scope="page" />`